Export a Google Sheet to PDF file with Python requests
Recently I have been trying to convert a Google Sheet into a PDF file, by retaining all formatting data. From my previous question, I have gotten a solution to request https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...id.../export?format=pdf. Replace ...id..., as @doubleunary mentioned.
This is how I am constructing the link.
URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"
ID = "1ZUG5Xlesc-e1EfGg_T16vamQ_igMXvPb6VNQoWZegDE"

PARAM = [
    '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf',
    '&size=LETTER',
    '&portrait=true',
    '&fitw=true',
    '&top_margin=0.75',
    '&bottom_margin=0.75',
    '&left_margin=0.7',
    '&right_margin=0.7',
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false',
    '&pagenum=UNDEFINED',
    '&gridlines=true',
    '&fzr=FALSE'
]

params = ''
for param in PARAM:
    params += param

CALL = URL + ID + params

Now, I have encountered the problem of authentication. I don't want to give view access to anyone with the link either.
Below is the code I've used for OAuth2, but I don't know how I can use the authentication to post a request.
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
    import os
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE"] = ' '

    client_id = xxx
    client_secret = xxx
    redirect_uri = 'http://localhost'

    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']
    oauth = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope)
    authorization_url, state = oauth.authorization_url(
        "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        access_type="offline",
        prompt="select_account")

    print(f'Please go to {authorization_url} and authorize access.')
    authorization_response = input('Enter the full callback URL - ')

    token = oauth.fetch_token(
            "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            code=authorization_response,
            client_secret=client_secret)

    r = oauth.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo')

    for i in r:
        print(i)

The code returns the correct user details, but when I try request.get(CALL) after authentication, it still returns a 401 code. How can I put the authentication to use?
I want to avoid things like Selenium, because they often result in Captcha problems.

Have you tried adding this scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file? Since you're accessing data from your drive and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly for removing access the file. You can read more about scopes here, Choose Google Drive API scopes.

@LimeHusky To be clear, drive.file scope won't work, unless the file is created by this script or access is granted via Google picker.

Your can send the token as query parameter. Append to PARAM before joining:
PARAM.append(f"&access_token={token}")

And as Lime Husky commented, you need appropriate scopes, specifically,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Or
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

